# XML to PHP for Soap call

Tags: php, xml, api, soap

I am trying to compile a Soap call with PHP (the params part of the call), but I am having trouble converting the XML nodes to PHP Soap to make the call.

I am trying to take this XML
https://gist.github.com/Davidlab/f40f386c65347f6d21e4
and convert it to a PHP soap (the params part of it).
If you look at the XML file you will see that there are 2  nodes and I need to translate that to this PHP sample that has only one  node.
https://gist.github.com/Davidlab/e3cc11a7c80a4c273d31

I can get it to work with one  but can not figure out the proper way to include another  within the call.

Thanks for any help you may provide.

Comment: is it a WSDL based SOAP web service?

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in SOAP functions in PHP. I just went through figuring out SOAP. After lots of Googling and emailing back and forth with tech support I figured out nobody really knows what SOAP is. :) Anyway the built in SOAP functions do all of the conversions for you. Very simple to use.

Comment: thanks but that is what I need help with. I understand soap has functions, but I can't seem to compile it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to figure out how your data structures should look is to do a little bit of discovery like this:

```
$wsdl = "http://the-location-of-the-wsdl";
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl);
var_dump($soapClient->__getFunctions());
var_dump($soapClient->__getTypes());
```

`__getFunctions()` will show you all the methods you can call, the data types they accept and return. `__getTypes()` will show you what the data structures look like.  Create your arrays or classes so they follow the same structure. This is much easier than trying to figure it out with raw XML.